# Connect Java Application with Multiple Database Servers Based on DB Server's Availability

Tags: java, spring, database-connection

I have developed an application using Java and Spring Framework. I have two Database Servers DB_Server_1 and DB_Server_2 which are synchronizing transactions. I have connected application with DB_Server_1 but if some day DB_Server_1 gets down then I want to shift my Application connection to DB_Server_2 without restarting or modifying anything.

One way which I am thinking to achieve this functionality is to check DB Connection exception and in catch block connect with other server but this might not be a good idea.

Please guide me for a proper way to achieve this functionality.

Thanks

Comment: You want a database and a JDBC driver which supports this (you might want a master/slave or replication setup). You don't want to do this manually.

Comment: At database level I am using Always ON feature of SQL Server and for that I am using the listener for connectivity and I don't have to bother at application level for such type of scenario. But for the above mentioned scenario I am not connecting to primary node and I want to use the secondary node(s) and if the node with which I am connected gets down then I should be able to switch my connection to other node.

Comment: As stated that should be handled by your driver. Don't do this at the application level.